# tex4ebook does not accept config file

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook, capacity

I installed today March 27 2022 new version of texlive. I made MWE which works well with pdfLatex. It works well with "tex4ebook -l myfile.tex". But, if I include minimal config file (from Michal's guide), I get

htlatex: ?    855      TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]

I have done during the last two years more than 50 e-books without major problems.

Now htlatex works well and dvi seems to be OK.

Why does TeX capacity overflow?

Comment: If you made a MWE, why not share it?

Comment: Don't put the code in the comments. Edit the question and use code blocks.

Comment: I can confirm that this happens with one of config files that I provided for you. It seems to be caused by the `\CutAt` command. The error goes away when you remove it.

Comment: Removing \CutAt corrects that particular problem but creates many others. In Windows environment \CutAt normally produces several html-files. If it does not exist - only one. It means that whole book is in one html-file. On screen Adobe Digital Editions makes random page breaks.

Is there any possibility to load earlier tex4ebook related files only?

Answer (score 1):

I've found some of the older configurations files I send you [in the past](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/588179/2891). It is this one:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\renewcommand\breakhtml{\section[page break]{}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{}
\makeatother
\CutAt{section,likesection,part}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

I've compiled the following MWE using this config file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Second}
\section{XXXX}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Compile using:

```
 tex4ebook -c config.cfg -a debug sample.tex
```

And it indeed fails:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\ltx:like ->\ltx:like 
                      \expandafter \let \csname likepart\endcsname \empty \e...
l.7 \CutAt{section,likesection,part}
                          
No pages of output.
Transcript written on sample.log.
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1
```

The culprit seems to be the `\CutAt` command. It splits the generated document to separate pages on `\section` commands. `tex4ebook` now uses this  command internally to split pages on `\chapter` for the book class, and `\section` for article. If you want to use custom splits, it now needs the `no-cut` option to be used.

I think that the correct config file should look like this:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,no-cut}
% \renewcommand\breakhtml{\section[page break]{}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{}
\makeatother
\CutAt{part,appendix} % split on \part
\CutAt{chapter,likechapter,appendix,part} % split on \chapter
\CutAt{likechapter,appendix,part}  % split on \chapter*
\CutAt{appendix,chapter,likechapter,part}  % split on \appendix
\CutAt{likesection,chapter,likechapter,appendix,part} % split on \section*
\CutAt{section,likesection,chapter,likechapter,appendix,part} % split on \section

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

In addition to the original `\CutAt` command, it also splits on `\chapter` and similar commands. Feel free to remove these new additions if you don't want this effect.

Comment: Your answer corrected my problem. Excellent! I noticed, however, one strange thing in my Windows 10 environment. If tex file's name is "MyFile.EPUB.tex", in resulting MyFile.EPUB.epub" the whole content exists twice - double number of pages. If I remove EPUB and use file name "MyFile.tex" the result is OK.

Comment: @TimoKuronen thanks for the report, I can confirm that. I've fixed it in tex4ebook sources.